Gitlab CICD - compare_to previous commit
In GItlab-CI Im trying to start a job only if $APP is equal to "my-app" and the file file.txt was changed compared to the last commit.
Currently my .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like this:
stages:
 - install_dependencies
 - build

variables:
  APP_NAME: "my-app"

install_dependencies:
  stage: install_dependencies
  image: doesnt matter
  script:
    - echo "Installing dependencies..."
  rules:
    - if: '$APP == "my-app"'
      changes:
        path:
          - file.txt
        compare_to: '$CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA'

build:
  stage: build
  image: doesnt matter
  script:
    - echo "Building my app..."
  dependencies:
    - install_dependencies


I have tried to change the compare_to to every option (for example: HEAD~, HEAD^, refs/heads/$CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA, refs/heads/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH, etc) but nothing worked for me.
I think there is something wrong with the compare_to.
Does someone knows how can I achive this?

I have never used the compare_to functionality, but it seems like variable expansion is not supported - see #369916.
However, from my understanding, your use case should work without compare_to but not for merge request pipelines. In pipelines on branches/tags (pipelines not associated with a merge request) only the latest commit should be evaluated:

Pipelines on branches or tags that don’t have an explicit association
with a merge request use a previous SHA to calculate the diff. This
calculation is equivalent to git diff HEAD~ and can cause unexpected
behavior, including:

The changes rule always evaluates to true when pushing a new branch or
a new tag to GitLab.
When pushing a new commit, the changed files are
calculated by using the previous commit as the base SHA.


To avoid the changes evaluating always to true when pushing a new branch, you could compare CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA to 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 see CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA.
As for merge request pipelines, I guess you need to manually do the check within the script and exit with 0 if the changes do not include your fie. Something like git --no-pager diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1 might be useful to get the files changed in the latest commit.

according to my experimentation, you can use relative commits.
for example to compare to the 5th parent:
install_dependencies:
  stage: install_dependencies
  image: doesnt matter
  script:
    - echo "Installing dependencies..."
  rules:
    - if: '$APP == "my-app"'
      changes:
        path:
          - file.txt
        compare_to: 'ref/heads/<default_branch>~5'

it's possible to use the HEAD and relative commit with ~ but not with ^.
compare_to: 'HEAD~3'

